# Any Server/Client model for Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rest, http

I developed an offline dictionary application in android that has local db built in sqlite shipped with it during installation. But the problem is that how to can I update, delete, add new record in the local db of application whenever it connects to the internet? 
Is there any specific protocol, technique, pattern or model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Apps will typically use [ReST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) architecture.

A good library to help you with this is [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

There isn't really a "universal" solution to your problem.

Comment: Found a nosql db couchbase that autosyncs server and client db and is really fast ...